# How are JSP/Servlet's executed in a Java-Capable webserver?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm playing with writing a Java-capable webserver. How do you get from your WAR/JSP to executable Java code? I've figured at this point FCGI is not available(I do have a client impl). What kind of mechanisms or specs are here? Are there any standards?

Comment: Please refer the spec :http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index-jsp-142185.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the spec http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index-jsp-142185.html

To brief you about the invocation when a war is deployed in the web server,the server refers the web.xml files for important configuration and then finds out the information regarding your webapp.All the configuration is loaded.If you try to hit an url mapped to a servlet then the class corresponding to it gets loaded.